# AWK ouput to separated file

Tags: awk

I am trying to split my file based on the patterns that it contains and store them as separate text files with that pattern.

I am using AWK to split my lines by two different separators ("\t" "_") and use $2 as file name and append that line ($0) into related file that is generated.

My command is:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="[_ \t]"}; {fn=$2"_HP100.txt"}; {print $0 >fn}' my_file.txt
```

Awk can generate text file named after my $2, and also it can give $0 as whole line when I printed separately. But My generated text files are always empty... Am I missing something?

My text file contains:

```
K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1773:1578_CGTCGCCATCGCTAGG    0    12    115297976    24    51M
K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1834:1578_TCGAACGACCGTTGCG    16    2    22709262    42    50M
K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1935:1578_GCCTATTCCCTCGTTG    16    18    54707729    42    51M
K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1955:1578_AGCGTCTTTCATGCTG    0    9    41603892    1    50M
K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1976:1578_TCATACCAAGTCTCCG    16    9    113429747    42    49M
K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1996:1578_TCATCGAACCTCGTTG    16    20    21594558    42    51M
K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2016:1578_TGGATCAACAGGACCA    0    16    13244975    27    51M
K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2057:1578_GATGCGTTTTCTGGTT    0    14    68520409    42    50M
K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2098:1578_CGTCGCCAAACTTAAC    0    8    94503004    42    50M
```

Expected output is `CGTCGCCAAACTTAAC_HP100.txt` file that contains all the lines with `_CGTCGCCAAACTTAAC` tag.

Comment: What version of AWK are you using (what you do get after doing `awk --version`)?

Comment: @emre : quick comment : ***`DONT`*** sort raw input data unless there's absolutely no other way around it - sorting the post-processed rows (e.g. aggregated, stratified, or summarized) is a lot faster.

Comment: There's something not mentioned in your question that is causing your problem as the script you posted will do what you want (with some caveats). If you [edit] your question to contain all relevant information then we can help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use this `awk` command:

```bash
awk -F '[\t_]' '{print $0 >> ($2 "_HP100.txt")}' file
```

Comment: Thank you! But that still gives empty text files :/

Comment: I suggest you test it with the small sample that you've shown here. Once that is working test on a bigger file.

Comment: I think it shouldn't be emty. if it could fint the tag, need to append the line as well :/

Comment: That's what this command does. All the lines with same `$2` value will be in a single file.

Comment: Yes @anubhava but it only generates same empty files as previous :( It generated 10 empty tag files. But ideally, at least 9 of them should contain one line. But all empty..

Comment: That is not happening when I test it. It created 10 files and all with a record from input file. What is your awk version? Also make sure input file doesn't have DOS line breaks

Comment: Can you try: `awk -F '[\t_]' '{print $0 > ($2 "_HP100.txt")}' file`?

Comment: I am using 4.1.3. This one also generate empty files. My input doesn't have any line breaks as well. I've tried with smaller file (With my example in the question). Interesting behaviour.... Should I split the input first? How do I decide size of the pieces :D

Comment: Yes it is working! The point is, command is not running as I expected. It is generating the file first and than filling the inside of it (Quite interestingly). Thats why I am getting empty files first... It generated 1G and 5G of files (without lose). I am trying it with larger sizes. Thank you for making me realizing it!!

Comment: You will have to wait till this process is running. It will create empty file first and start writing when it flushes input buffer.

Comment: Yes that was the problem.. I thought all files should be generated with data in the beginning.

Comment: @EmreTaylanDuman regarding `My input doesn't have any line breaks as well.` - you should state that in your question and show such input as your sample input rather than showing input that does have line breaks. I also see mention of 50G files in the comments above - if your files are particularly large then you should also tell us about that in your question. Just splitting your input file into smaller chunks based on number of bytes will almost certainly result in incorrect output and doesn't solve the problem of no line breaks.

Comment: If this answer doesn't require calling the awk script in a loop then you can replace `>>` with `>` to get probably more desirable semantics in that it'll empty the output file first. If it does require the awk script to be called in a shell loop - there's almost certainly a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following `awk` code. Its a combination of `awk` + `sort` + `cut` + `awk` solution, this will help us in case you have multiple lines where 2nd fields are same and you want to save all same $2 lines in same output file. This is sorting them from $2(by making 2nd field as 1st field to sort it and then using only required/actual portion of input only).

```bash
awk -F'_|\t' '{print $2,$0}' Input_file  | sort | cut -d' ' -f2- | 
awk -F'_|\t' '
prev!=$2{
  close(outputFile)
  outputFile=$2"_HP100.txt"
}
{
  print $0 > (outputFile)
  prev=$2
}
'
```

***NOTE:*** Pass your Input_file to first used `awk` in above code. Also this code is good for small files.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast response! My input file is a bit large (50gb). Takes some time to process. Couldn't get any output yet. Do you think cut should use tab instead of space? Because all the seperators are tab

Comment: @emretaylanDuman, ok, do you have multiple entries for $2, I mean more than 1 lines could go to same name file? Kindly confirm this case once.

Comment: Yes. That was the point that I forgot to mention. I have multiple entries and all of them should be stored in one text file.

Comment: @emretaylanDuman, ok cool then this solution will really help you, since its taking care of many things. Like: closing output file in backend, I sorted them so that we can make it quick. Let me think to make it more faster and till then you can let me know if you got any result yet?

Comment: I think sorting could take some more time. I was thinking it can be faster if it finds the tag appends the line if there is already a file there (generate if its not). I am not sure how slower it can get if there is multiple non-closed files backend

Comment: @emretaylanDuman, OR try one thing. First run: `awk -F'_|\t' '{print $2,$0}' Input_file  | sort | cut -d' ' -f2-  > temp && mv temp Input_file` command which will sort the contents of actual file(make sure to change Input_file name with your actual file's name) AND then run on newly sorted Input_file `awk -F'_|\t' 'prev!=$2{close(outputFile);outputFile=$2"_HP100.txt"} {print $0 > (outputFile);prev=$2}' Input_file` this should be REALLY FAST, let me know how it goes.

Comment: @emretaylanDuman, so its like I have broken my code into 2 parts and requesting you to run it then.

Comment: Yes it still running the first part :/

Comment: @emretaylanDuman, not sure this looks too much slow, what's your system configuration, memory, cpu etc?

Comment: @EmreTaylanDuman Regarding `I think sorting could take some more time` - for very large input files with many output files to be produced, the time `sort` takes to sort the input is usually far less than the time it takes for awk to manage opening/closing output files.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I have in mind to deal with the `50GB` issue is to collect a certain amount each round, then when the input arrays reach a fixed threshold, output the rows according to their file names

instead of nonstop concat-ing into a very very long string - the current approach uses one array for the rows themselves, and one more for mapping filenames to `row #s (aka NR)` :

1. collect until reaching threshold (i didn't set one that's up to u)
2. dump out all data in arrays to files
   — also allows for re-creation of original input row order

   - use `print (. . .) >> (fn)` instead of `>`, just in case
3. use `split("", arr)` to reset both arrays to a mint state
   — it's cleaner and more portable than `delete arr` statement
4. host system resource friendly

   - minimizes concurrent resource usage on the host system by only requiring one single instance of `awk`
   - the threshold you set would also constrain RAM usage at any moment to a sane level
   - avoids the need to use shell loops, `xargs`, or `gnu-parallel`
   - avoids nonstop `close(fn)`
5. avoids wasting time performing any amount of data `sort`-ing

> ```
> mawk '1;1;1;1;1;1;1' raw_input.txt | shuf | 
>
> mawk2 '
> BEGIN {  OFS = "_HP100.txt"
>           FS  = "^[^_]+_|[ \t].+$" 
> }  { ___[ NR ] = $_
>       sub(OFS, _, $!(NF = NF))
>        sub( "$", "=" NR,____[$_]) 
> } END { 
>     OFS = "\f\r\t\t"
>     for(_ in  ___) { print _, ___[_] } 
>     for(_ in ____) { print _,____[_] } } '
> ```

```
1
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2016:1578_TGGATCAACAGGACCA    0    16    13244975    27    51M
2
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2098:1578_CGTCGCCAAACTTAAC    0    8    94503004    42    50M
3
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1955:1578_AGCGTCTTTCATGCTG    0    9    41603892    1    50M
4
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2098:1578_CGTCGCCAAACTTAAC    0    8    94503004    42    50M
5
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1976:1578_TCATACCAAGTCTCCG    16    9    113429747    42    49M
6
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2057:1578_GATGCGTTTTCTGGTT    0    14    68520409    42    50M
7
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2057:1578_GATGCGTTTTCTGGTT    0    14    68520409    42    50M
8
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1955:1578_AGCGTCTTTCATGCTG    0    9    41603892    1    50M
9
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1996:1578_TCATCGAACCTCGTTG    16    20    21594558    42    51M
10
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2057:1578_GATGCGTTTTCTGGTT    0    14    68520409    42    50M
11
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1935:1578_GCCTATTCCCTCGTTG    16    18    54707729    42    51M
12
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1976:1578_TCATACCAAGTCTCCG    16    9    113429747    42    49M
13
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2016:1578_TGGATCAACAGGACCA    0    16    13244975    27    51M
14
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1955:1578_AGCGTCTTTCATGCTG    0    9    41603892    1    50M
15
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1976:1578_TCATACCAAGTCTCCG    16    9    113429747    42    49M
16
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1834:1578_TCGAACGACCGTTGCG    16    2    22709262    42    50M
17
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1955:1578_AGCGTCTTTCATGCTG    0    9    41603892    1    50M
18
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1955:1578_AGCGTCTTTCATGCTG    0    9    41603892    1    50M
19
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1834:1578_TCGAACGACCGTTGCG    16    2    22709262    42    50M
20
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2057:1578_GATGCGTTTTCTGGTT    0    14    68520409    42    50M
21
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2098:1578_CGTCGCCAAACTTAAC    0    8    94503004    42    50M
22
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1955:1578_AGCGTCTTTCATGCTG    0    9    41603892    1    50M
23
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1976:1578_TCATACCAAGTCTCCG    16    9    113429747    42    49M
24
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1976:1578_TCATACCAAGTCTCCG    16    9    113429747    42    49M
25
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1996:1578_TCATCGAACCTCGTTG    16    20    21594558    42    51M
26
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1955:1578_AGCGTCTTTCATGCTG    0    9    41603892    1    50M
27
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1996:1578_TCATCGAACCTCGTTG    16    20    21594558    42    51M
28
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2098:1578_CGTCGCCAAACTTAAC    0    8    94503004    42    50M
29
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1773:1578_CGTCGCCATCGCTAGG    0    12    115297976    24    51M
30
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1773:1578_CGTCGCCATCGCTAGG    0    12    115297976    24    51M
31
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1996:1578_TCATCGAACCTCGTTG    16    20    21594558    42    51M
32
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1834:1578_TCGAACGACCGTTGCG    16    2    22709262    42    50M
33
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2016:1578_TGGATCAACAGGACCA    0    16    13244975    27    51M
34
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1773:1578_CGTCGCCATCGCTAGG    0    12    115297976    24    51M
35
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2016:1578_TGGATCAACAGGACCA    0    16    13244975    27    51M
36
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1996:1578_TCATCGAACCTCGTTG    16    20    21594558    42    51M
37
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1935:1578_GCCTATTCCCTCGTTG    16    18    54707729    42    51M
38
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1773:1578_CGTCGCCATCGCTAGG    0    12    115297976    24    51M
39
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2057:1578_GATGCGTTTTCTGGTT    0    14    68520409    42    50M
40
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1976:1578_TCATACCAAGTCTCCG    16    9    113429747    42    49M
41
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2057:1578_GATGCGTTTTCTGGTT    0    14    68520409    42    50M
42
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1834:1578_TCGAACGACCGTTGCG    16    2    22709262    42    50M
43
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1834:1578_TCGAACGACCGTTGCG    16    2    22709262    42    50M
44
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1773:1578_CGTCGCCATCGCTAGG    0    12    115297976    24    51M
45
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2016:1578_TGGATCAACAGGACCA    0    16    13244975    27    51M
46
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1773:1578_CGTCGCCATCGCTAGG    0    12    115297976    24    51M
47
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2016:1578_TGGATCAACAGGACCA    0    16    13244975    27    51M
48
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1976:1578_TCATACCAAGTCTCCG    16    9    113429747    42    49M
49
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1996:1578_TCATCGAACCTCGTTG    16    20    21594558    42    51M
50
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1773:1578_CGTCGCCATCGCTAGG    0    12    115297976    24    51M
51
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2098:1578_CGTCGCCAAACTTAAC    0    8    94503004    42    50M
52
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1935:1578_GCCTATTCCCTCGTTG    16    18    54707729    42    51M
53
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2098:1578_CGTCGCCAAACTTAAC    0    8    94503004    42    50M
54
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1935:1578_GCCTATTCCCTCGTTG    16    18    54707729    42    51M
55
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2057:1578_GATGCGTTTTCTGGTT    0    14    68520409    42    50M
56
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1935:1578_GCCTATTCCCTCGTTG    16    18    54707729    42    51M
57
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1935:1578_GCCTATTCCCTCGTTG    16    18    54707729    42    51M
58
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2098:1578_CGTCGCCAAACTTAAC    0    8    94503004    42    50M
59
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1996:1578_TCATCGAACCTCGTTG    16    20    21594558    42    51M
60
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1834:1578_TCGAACGACCGTTGCG    16    2    22709262    42    50M
61
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1935:1578_GCCTATTCCCTCGTTG    16    18    54707729    42    51M
62
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:2016:1578_TGGATCAACAGGACCA    0    16    13244975    27    51M
63
        K00295:342:HNYVTBBXY:5:1101:1834:1578_TCGAACGACCGTTGCG    16    2    22709262    42    50M
TCATACCAAGTCTCCG_HP100.txt
        =5=12=15=23=24=40=48
CGTCGCCATCGCTAGG_HP100.txt
        =29=30=34=38=44=46=50
TCATCGAACCTCGTTG_HP100.txt
        =9=25=27=31=36=49=59
AGCGTCTTTCATGCTG_HP100.txt
        =3=8=14=17=18=22=26
GCCTATTCCCTCGTTG_HP100.txt
        =11=37=52=54=56=57=61
GATGCGTTTTCTGGTT_HP100.txt
        =6=7=10=20=39=41=55
TCGAACGACCGTTGCG_HP100.txt
        =16=19=32=42=43=60=63
TGGATCAACAGGACCA_HP100.txt
        =1=13=33=35=45=47=62
CGTCGCCAAACTTAAC_HP100.txt
        =2=4=21=28=51=53=58
```

Comment: Thank you for that detailed approach. Now it is running with regular awk method. Once its completed, I will run this one as well. I will post the performance parameters as well. Thanks

Comment: @EmreTaylanDuman : run it with `mawk2`, and you'll see minimum 20% time savings, all else being equal